# Pytest, get IntegrityError when inserting ForeignKey by id

Tags: python, django, pytest

I have such table structure

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ChildModel(models.Model):
        parent_instrument = models.ForeignKey(
            to=ParentModel,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
            null=True,
            blank=True,
        )
        instrument = models.ForeignKey(
            to=ParentModel,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
            null=True,
            blank=True,
        )
```

Then I run my pytest with empty database, where I test such logic

```
try:
    ChildModel.objects.update_or_create(
        parent_instrument_id=symbol1,
        instrument_id=symbol2,
    )
except IntegrityError:
    self._create_instrument(symbol1, symbol2)
```

I don't get IntegrityError. ChildModel is just saved without existing ParentModel symbol. Is it possible to avoid such behaviour?

Comment: Well, you refer to a non existing `ParentModel`, so how would you be able to construct such `ChildModel` if you refer to a non-existing parent?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem - It's just part of the code and the logic, just to describe the issue I faced

Answer (score -1):

You won't get an IntegrityError because your foreign keys are configured to allow null values.

**UPDATE:** it looks like I misunderstood the question

Given this class

```
class SubjectCategory(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

This test (passing None as the values) passes:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_subject_category_none_object():
    with pytest.raises(IntegrityError):
        subject_category = SubjectCategory.objects.get_or_create(
            subject_id=None, category_id=None
        )
```

This test (passing an explicitly wrong value) fails:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_subject_category_invalid_id():
    with pytest.raises(IntegrityError):
        subject_category = SubjectCategory.objects.get_or_create(
            subject_id=-1, category_id=-1
        )
```

This test (explicitly wrong value and catch any exception) ALSO fails

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_subject_category_any_exception():
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        subject_category = SubjectCategory.objects.get_or_create(
            subject_id=-1, category_id=-1
        )
```

It gets weirder.  if I run a single test, like so:

```
pytest path/to/tests/test_subject.py::test_create_subject_category_any_exception
```

I get this message at the end of my test run:

```
1 passed, 1 error in 0.52s
```

I only ran one test ... why am I getting two results?

I can only assume that the FK checks are being done at commit time, not when the statement is being executed.

My advice would be -- don't try to set the ID values for foreign keys directly, use `parent_instrument=some_object`.

Comment: Same behaviour without allowing null values

Comment: Thanks for update. Can you also say, if I try SubjectCategory.objects.get - will it trigger extra query?

Comment: If I understand the question....`get_or_create` does exactly what it says.  It will run a `get()` and if no matching object is returned, it will run a `create()`.